# Ruby match part of escaped html string

Tags: regex

How do I match the id of this escaped html string? Part of the string starts with id=\" and ends with \" In this example I need art_images_attributes_0_attachement

```
"<div class=\"input string optional\"><label class=\"string optional\" for=\"art_images_attributes_0_attachement\"> Attachement</label><input class=\"string optional\" id=\"art_images_attributes_0_attachement\" maxlength=\"255\" name=\"art[images_attributes][0][attachement]\" size=\"50\" type=\"text\" /></div>"
 => "<div class=\"input string optional\"><label class=\"string optional\" for=\"art_images_attributes_0_attachement\"> Attachement</label><input class=\"string optional\" id=\"art_images_attributes_0_attachement\" maxlength=\"255\" name=\"art[images_attributes][0][attachement]\" size=\"50\" type=\"text\" /></div>"
```

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will capture your desired outputp:

```
/id="([^"]*)"/
```

And a Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/dtXqK2GBPe

Note that there is not actually a `\` character before the quotation marks, in Ruby the content of the string `"id=\"test\""` is `id="test"`, the `\` is just there to escape any `"` that should be included.

And so that it will also work with escaped quotes inside of the `id` value, you can use this:

```
/id="([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"/
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/b66eWno8Ce

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for. string.match(/id="([^"]*)"/)[1]

Answer (score 0):

Regex-wise this would do it:

```
id=\\\"(.+?)\\\"
```

Comment: Nick, your example returns nil

Comment: As explained by Andrew's answer.  My (naive) answer was based on the idea that I needed to match exactly what was in your question - I didn't appreciate that the \s were to be ignored.